# How to run cbioportal tomcat war using heroku's webapp-runner.jar

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, heroku, jndi

I've been following the tutorial from Heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner) to learn how to run a war file using webapp-runner.jar. Now I would like to run cbioportal (https://github.com/cbioportal/cbioportal) on heroku. I've managed to add the webapp-runner.jar as a dependency, see: https://github.com/inodb/cbioportal/tree/heroku.

When I run the following from the repo directory:

```
java -Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory \
    -jar portal/target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port 9099 portal/target/portal
```

I get an error like this:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityMapper' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-business.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-business.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'businessDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'businessDataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-business.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:comp].
```

I've tried passing the context.xml of my local Tomcat install and setting the mysql connection string directly in the file but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need to register the DB URL as a JNDI resource in a `context.xml` file, maybe like this:

```
<Context>
  <Resource name="jdbc/cbioportal" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
               username="user" password="pass" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname"/>
</Context>
```

Then you'd need to add that context XML as an option to the `java` command like this:

```
$ java ... \
    -jar portal/target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar \
    --context-xml context.xml --port 9099 \
    portal/target/portal
```

For the `url` in the `context.xml`, you'll have to get that from your `$ heroku config` and convert it into a jdbc url. It is available at runtime as [`$JDBC_DATABASE_URL`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-the-jdbc_database_url), but I'm not sure how to get that into the context.xml dynamically.

For that reason, I think you're better off not using JNDI if possible. Can you configure the DB params directly in your app?

I got the JNDI name from [this line in your config](https://github.com/inodb/cbioportal/blob/8a255216cccad6c3f329e63c84a14d6f464161fc/src/main/resources/portal.properties.EXAMPLE#L6)

For more on JNDI with Tomcat see [the Tomcat docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html).

For more on webapp-runner options see the [project readme](https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner#options).

Comment: For anyone reading this. Using a context.xml didin't work, not using JNDI solved the problem. Thanks!